# save as json or map to django model and then save?

Tags: json, django

So I have this data I want to save using postgreSQL and Django. The data will come from an external source in the format of json according to the following format:

"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"RESPONSE": {
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"RESULT": {
"type": "array",
"items": {
"properties": {
"_attr_id": {
"type": "string"
},
"TrainStation": {
"type": "array",
"items": {
"type": "object",
"$ref": "#/definitions/TrainStation"
}
},
"INFO": {
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"LASTMODIFIED": {
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"_attr_datetime": {
"type": "string",
"format": "date-time"
}
},
"additionalProperties": false
},
"LASTCHANGEID": {
"type": "string"
},
"EVALRESULT": {
"type": "array",
"items": {},
"additionalProperties": true
},

My questions, what is the best way to save this data if I want to use later run operations on this. Is it to save it as jsonb or should I actually create a django model to map it and save it that way?